# Converting ID values in substring of varchar to it's lookup values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL column of type varchar that is meant to contain SQL conditions, eg (3 rows below):

```
WHERE Language = 1 OR Region = 10
WHERE Color= 3 OR Region = 10
WHERE Status = 1 OR Region = 10 AND Language = 1
```

I need to create a query to get the lookup values of these that can be sent to any non technical person. The output would be:

```
WHERE Language = English OR Region = Canada
WHERE Color= Red OR Region = Canada
WHERE Status = Active OR Region = Canada AND Language = English
```

I know I can first put all the lookups in a temp table and then use the `REPLACE` function, but I was wondering if there's any better (and shorter) way to do this? Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear what you want. Region is always  `Canada`?

Comment: Hi Neer, the region can change, this was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would create subquery column values ready to replace originals, f.eks for Regions:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('%Region = ', Region,'%') ConditionToJoin,
  CONCAT('Region = ', Region) ConditionToFind, 
  CONCAT('Region = ', RegionName) ConditionToReplace
FROM Regions
```

The join this sub query with condition rows using LIKE operator and ConditionToJoin column.

There is also a question if you need to handle situations like:

- Region=1
- Region =1
  etc...

Alternatively you could write user function to wash data and perform all replacements, something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION replaceLookups(@condition VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
  @string_replacement VARCHAR(MAX), @string_pattern VARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @string_pattern = SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT('Region = ', Region) FROM Regions WHERE @condition LIKE CONCAT('%Region = ', Region, '%')

  SET @string_replacement = SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT('Region = ', RegionName) FROM Regions WHERE @condition LIKE CONCAT('%Region = ', Region, '%')

  SET @ret = REPLACE(@condition, @string_pattern, @string_replacement)
  ... --and so on for each lookup
  RETURN @ret
END
```

Word of warning. Above code was written from top of my head - might need some work. Also I wouldn't expect great performance.

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for. I have a column that has rows and each row is a hardcoded "WHERE" condition. I need to loop through each row and remove the ID and replace it with VALUE while keeping all other data as is.